# How do I know when I installed package FOO

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, package-management

I was wondering if I installed 'Tor' on my Ubuntu 14.04 or it was shipped as a default package since I hadn't remembered installation by myself. So what's the way to find out if a package is user-installed and when was the installation date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To figure out if a package (Tor here) is installed by user, run this in terminal:

```
apt-cache show tor | grep Priority
```

if the priority was `optional‍‍‍‍‍`, The package was installed by user, If was `standard` (`important` on Debian ) it's a default installed package.

Now to find out when the package is installed, check the apt logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Older log files have been archived as `gz`. It might be needed to check them (after extraction) if the installation procedure was way back. 
For me these lines in `history.log` indicate when I installed `tor` and then forgot about it:

```
Start-Date: 2015-01-24 22:42:00 
Commandline: apt-get install tor 
Install: tor:amd64 (0.2.4.20-1), torsocks:amd64 (1.3-3, automatic), tor-geoipdb:amd64 (0.2.4.20-1, automatic) 
End-Date: 2015-01-24 22:42:06
```

Source [Site chat room]: [Chat message #1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20349185#20349185) and [Chat message #2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20349475#20349475), (Thanks to @derobert, @terdon and @muru)

Comment: Which packages are part of the default installation depends on the installation method and (for some methods) on selections during the installation. You can't rely on the priority for that.

Comment: @Gilles Does it mean if an optional package was checked during installation, its priority would turn to `standard` and will be shown that way in later queries? So what do you suggest?

Comment: No, the priority of a package doesn't depend on what was done during installation. “Optional” doesn't really mean “not installed by default”, because different installation methods install different packages.

Comment: apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop shows Optional, while it's installed by default

Comment: @Maythux Yes you're right. Do you have any suggestion? Since `ubuntu-desktop` is a MetaPackage, I tried some other metapackages like `ubuntu-minimal`, `ubuntu-standard` and they weren't optional. Although `ubuntu-restricted-extras` was optional!

Comment: @DummyBeginner http://askubuntu.com/questions/635974/is-this-package-shipped-by-default